# How do I find the Energy Density Function of $g(t)$ if i am not given an input or impulse response?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, continuous-signals, signal-energy

$$g(t)=\frac{12a}{t^2+a^2}$$

I need to find the Energy Density Function of the signal, but everywhere I look has an input and an impulse response. Does anyone know how to solve this. Would I just take the absolute value of it, square it and then integrate it?

Comment: Read up on the difference between "Signals" and "Systems". It's super important to not confuse the two and it's a fairly common confusion for beginners. Good news: it's quite easy to get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to [energy spectral density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Energy_spectral_density), then you need to compute the squared magnitude of the Fourier transform of $g(t)$:

$$\big|G(\omega)\big|^2=\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt\right|^2\tag{1}$$